# Differentiate lists according to translations

Tags: python, django, list, multilingual

I have a multilingual field which i used hvad package.
I have a script like below, which i use for the tastypie dehydration.

```
    array = []
    for t in bundle.obj.facilities.filter(foo_type = i.foo_type):
        for field in get_translatable_fields(t.foo_type.__class__):
            for translation in t.foo_type.translations.all():
                value = getattr(translation, field)
                array.append(value)
                print array
```

But i get all the language translations in the same list. Do you have any idea to have different lists belong to different languages.

I just want to have different arrays that differentiate during `for translation in ....` iteration

Comment: Do you want a dictionary of arrays, where the keys are languages? Also, why do you call it `array` first then `array_all` later? Are they not the same?

Comment: Yes.. keys are languages and the values are arrays consist many of translated fields.

Comment: It's not the original code. I changed the field names, but forget the array_all. fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in a dictionary, indexed by the `translation`, using a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections

dict_all = collections.defaultdict(list)
for t in bundle.obj.facilities.filter(foo_type = i.foo_type):
    for field in get_translatable_fields(t.foo_type.__class__):
        for translation in t.foo_type.translations.all():
            value = getattr(translation, field)
            dict_all[translation.language_code].append(value)
```

If you'd like to turn it back into a regular dictionary afterwards (instead of a `defaultdict`):

```
dict_all = dict(dict_all.items())
```